# Keypress event in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I just started learning DOM events, i was using keypress event to make some event happen when i press the enter key. It is working fine.

```
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){

        if(event.keyCode === 13){
            console.log("enter was pressed");
        }
    });
```

But i read on MDN event reference that **keypress** event is **deprecated**.

[MDN keypress reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event)

What is the reason of its depreciation and what is the new alternative of keypress event ?

Comment: `Since this event has been deprecated, you should look to use beforeinput or keydown instead.`

Comment: The reason for deprecating it is no more than theoretical purity. It's called "keypress" but it's not about keys - it's about character input, Hence the idea is to use "beforeinput" instead. Except beforeinput isn't implemented in Firefox. So the UiEvents spec can't exit draft status, and therefore can't truly deprecate keypress, merely wish its deprecation. In any case keypress isn't going away, since millions of web sites would stop working if it did, so if it does what you need, just use it.

Answer (score 1):

[onkeyDown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeydown) and [onKeyUp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) are the alternativies for this. To maintain performance you can use Debounce for your logic.